# Replace values of an array of objects from another array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have this main array:

```
 const purchaseData = [
  {
    product_id: "product_id_1",
    localized_title: "Product Title 1",
    ... other attributes
  },
  {
    product_id: "product_id_2",
    localized_title: "Product Title 2",
    ... other attributes
  },
```

And I'd like to replace the localized_title with an array that contains some updated localized_title for certain product_ids

example:

```
updatedData = [
  {
    product_id: "product_id_1",
    localized_title: "Updated Product Title 1",
    ...other random attributes // different from the attributes in the objects of purchaseData
  },
];
```

In this case, the purchaseData's first child only should have its localized_title updated. Is there an elegant way of doing this without using For...lopps and without mutating the data? I've tried many ways but I seem to write too many lines of code (not very clean).

This is what I tried:

```
const updatedData = purchaseData.map(obj => {
    const foundObject = originalProducts.find(
      o => o.product_id === obj.product_id,
    );
    const localized_title = foundObject && foundObject.localized_title
    if (localized_title) {
        return {...obj, localized_title}
    }
    return obj;
  });
```

Comment: Maybe you can try with `map()` or `reduce()`.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? What is *"unclean"* about it, and what actual *problem* is that causing?

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder and I can tell you, as someone who reviews code all day long, I'd much rather see "too many" lines of code than too few "clever" lines of code.

Comment: If you have working code and you want advice on how to improve it, [codereview.se] is the place to post it. You'll need to post your full code, not just a description.

Comment: I updated the question to include what I tried. I don't need to merge, but instead to replace some values, because the 2 arrays contain objects which have different attributes

Comment: Why is this bad? Does it do the job? Is spending more time optimizing the readability going to improve it enough to be worth it?

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about other developers reading this code, I feel like it's too complicated :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be worth it to optimize your lookup using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to reduce the search for `foundObject` from O(n) to O(1), and instead of having two `return` statements, you could combine them into one:

```
const originalProductsMap = new Map(
  originalProducts.map(o => [o.product_id, o])
);

const updatedData = purchaseData.map(oldData => {
  const newData = originalProductsMap.get(oldData.product_id);
  const localized_title = newData && newData.localized_title;

  return localized_title
    ? { ...oldData, localized_title }
    : oldData;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a Map to simplify retrieving the objects(this also makes the code O(n)):

```
  const productById = new Map(products.map(it => ([it.product_id, it])));

  const updated = purchases.map(purchase => {
    const product = productById.get(purchase.product_id);

    if (product && product.localized_title) {
      return { ...purchase, localized_title: product.localized_title, };
    }

    return purchase;
 });
```

Comment: Also your logic isn't exactly equivalent. Your `if` would need to be `if (product && product.localized_title)`. That's why I stored the intermediate expression to a `const` and used the shorthand property notation instead.

Comment: @patrick indeed, wasn't quite sure if that behaviour is wanted. I'd still prefer `if(product && ...)` then as it clearly states the intent.

Comment: I agree with the logic mentioned by @PatrickRoberts `if (product && product.localized_title)`

Comment: @skoltz if that was intended then ... Also I rejected your edit cause I think removing the `data` increases readability ...

Comment: @Skoltz do keep in mind that if `localized_title` is an empty string on the new object, the old object will be returned since `""` is false-y.